# Passing v-model into a checkbox inside a Component in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to embed a checkbox inside a Vue3 Component and have the `v-model` binding passed down to the checkbox.

Inside the Component:

```
<!-- Tile.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
    <input type=checkbox v-model="$attrs">
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {inheritAttrs: false}
</script>
```

Then in an outside file:

```
<template>
<Tile value="carrot" v-model="foods" />
<Tile value="tomatoes" v-model="foods" />
</template>
<script setup>
var foods = ref([]);
</script>
```

How do I achieve this?

The documentation says that `v-model` is just a shorthand for `:modelValue` and `@update:modelValue` but this is not universal as Vue obviously behaves differently for  form elements such as smartly listening to `onchange` instead of `oninput` and modifying the property `checked` instead of `value` depending on the node.

If I use `v-model` on the outer component, how do I forward it to the checkbox and get the same smart behavior that Vue has?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found tons of controversial information. Some recommend using `@input` event ([Vue 3 custom checkbox component with v-model and array of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69479467/vue-3-custom-checkbox-component-with-v-model-and-array-of-items)). Some recommend emitting `modelValue:update` instead of `update:modelValue` (https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/2667#issuecomment-732886315). Etc.. Following worked for me after hour of trial and error on latest `Vuejs3`

Child

```
<template>
  <div class="form-check noselect">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" :id="id" :checked="modelValue" @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.checked)" />
    <label class="form-check-label" :for="id"><slot /></label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup() {
    return {
      id: uuidv4(),
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Parent:

```
<Checkbox v-model="someVariable">Is true?</Checkbox>
```

you can verify that it works but doing this in parent:

```
    var someVariable= ref(false);

    watch(someVariable, () => {
      console.log(someVariable.value);
    });
```

p.s. The other solution above does not work for me. Author recommends using `value` property. But in example he passes `v-model` attribute. So I don't know exactly how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Thank you -- for spending the hour so I don't have to spend 3!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the behavior by using emits to keep data in sync and behave as default v-model behavior. Checkbox component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      :checked="value"
      @change="$emit('input', $event.target.checked)"
    />
    {{ text }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "inputcheckbox",
  props: ["value", "text"],
};
</script>
```

And in the parent component you can have as many checkboxes you want.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <maincontent :showContent="showContent" />
    <inputcheckbox text="one" v-model="checkedOne" />
    <inputcheckbox text="two" v-model="checkedTwo" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is a vue 2 example but is applicable to vue 3 as well.  Hope this was helpful. Sandbox with this behavior:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/confident-buck-kith5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thanks for the example, but it still doesn't duplicate the full extent of the flexibility of Vue's `v-model`. With Vue, I can use the same `v-model:variableName` for different checkboxes and Vue will automatically collapse them into an array if the variable name is the same.